# Unable to make build with Soomla State & Economy Sync plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, soomla

I integrated Grow Compete, Grow Spend and Grow Ultimate modules to my Unity Project. When I tried to make build the project, I receive two errors that says :

> > CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
> >     C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\ADTBundle\adt_bundle\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe
> >     package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
> >     "res" -I
> >     "C:/Users/halil.cosgun/Desktop/ADTBundle/adt_bundle/sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar"
> >     -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms -S "C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\SoomlaWorkout\SoomlaWorkout\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res"
>
> stderr[ res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_dark 1.xml: Invalid file
>   name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_dark 2.xml: Invalid file name:
>   must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_light
>   ... ...
>   res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.11.png:0:
>   error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already
>   defined.
>   res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.11.png:0:
>   error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already
>   defined.
>   res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.11.png:0:
>   error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already
>   defined.
>   res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png:0: error:
>   Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already defined.
>   res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\draw

And

> > Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
> >     C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\ADTBundle\adt_bundle\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe
> >     package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
> >     "res" -I
> >     "C:/Users/halil.cosgun/Desktop/ADTBundle/adt_bundle/sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar"
> >     -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms -S "C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\SoomlaWorkout\SoomlaWorkout\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res"
>
> stderr[ res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_dark 1.xml: Invalid file
>   name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_dark 2.xml: Invalid file name:
>   must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_light
>   1.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_light 2.xml: Invalid file name:
>   must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_dark
>   1.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_dark 2.xml: Invalid file name:
>   must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_light
>   1.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_light 2.xml: Invalid file name:
>   must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   res\drawable-mdpi-v4\ic_plusone_medium_off_client 1.png: Invalid file
>   name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   res\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_plusone_medium_off_client 1.png: Invalid file
>   name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\ic_plusone_medium_off_client 1.png: Invalid file
>   name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_plusone_medium_off_client 1.png: Invalid
>   file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   ... ...
>   res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.11.png:0:
>   error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already
>   defined.
>   res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.11.png:0:
>   error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already
>   defined.
>   res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.11.png:0:
>   error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already
>   defined.
>   res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally defined here.
>
> res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png:0: error:
>   Resource entry common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark is already defined.
>   res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.10.png:0:
>   Originally

[image: Here is my assets folder]

Could you please help me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, you might have better luck in the SOOMLA forums - http://answers.soom.la